# Enable a mercurial extension in .hgrc only if it's present

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I have a lot of things in my `.hgrc` file so I keep it in a repository and share it between computers.

I have a lot of extensions enabled in the `[extensions]` section, but I don't necessarily want to use all of them on all of my computers.

Unfortunately, whenever I try to use Mercurial with my shared `.hgrc` file on a computer where I don't have every single one of the specified extensions installed, I get a message of the form:

```
*** failed to import extension evolve from $HG_EXTENSIONS/mutable-history/hgext/evolve.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/botond/programs/mercurial/extensions/mutable-history/hgext/evolve.py'
```

*every time I run any `hg` command!*

Is there a way to avoid this? For example, is there a way to specify in the `.hgrc` file, "load this extension if you can find it, otherwise don't load it and just be quiet about it"? (Then, if I actually try to *use* the extension, I'd get an error.)

---

additional search terms:

- How to conditionally enable Mercurial extensions
- Activate Mercurial extension based on condition
- Enable a Mercurial extension only if it exists

Answer (score 1):

- Use [Projrc extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ProjrcExtension)
- Enable all and any extensions in projrc's config
- Disable missing|not needed files in `.hg/hgrc`

Comment: What do you mean by "Disable missing|not needed files in `.hg/hgrc`"?

Comment: @HighCommander4 - Mercurial have syntax for disabling extensions, enabled on higher-levels config-files [`bar = !/path/to/extension/bar.py`

`baz = !`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UsingExtensions#Enabling_an_extension)

Comment: @LazyBadger: no better solution, though?

Comment: @0xC0000022L - I least *I don't know*

Comment: @LazyBadger: alright. Thanks. Just hoped you may have come across something meanwhile. Thanks for the pointer with Projrc, it's new to me.